# MemoryRouter inside BrowserRouter with Link that controls BrowserRouter

Tags: typescript, react-router

I have a Component that reads its state from Location. But sometimes when nested, I don't want it to modify the location so I wrap it within `MemoryRouter`. That way it can still read and update its state from location (in memory) but browser url does not change.

```html
<BrowserRouter>
    ...
    <MemoryRouter>
        <Component>
            <Link to="somerouter">link</Link>
        </Component>
    </MemoryRouter>
    ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

I'd like to use `react-router-dom`'s Link component for navigating to other parts of the app from within Component. However, the Link does nothing as it's inside MemoryRouter.

I don't want to use `<a>` because that would lose fluent redraws.

**Is there a way to force Link to control top Router and not the first one in hierarchy?**

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution where I store top router context and then pass it into my Link component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { __RouterContext as RouterContext, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export const TopReactRouterContext = React.createContext<RouteComponentProps>(null as unknown as RouteComponentProps);

export const Router: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RouterContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => (
        <TopReactRouterContext.Provider value={context}>
          {children}
        </TopReactRouterContext.Provider>
      )}
    </RouterContext.Consumer>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

```
import * as H from 'history';
import React from 'react';
import { __RouterContext as RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import { Link as ReactRouterLink, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TopReactRouterContext } from './Router';

export const Link = <S extends H.LocationState>(
  props: React.PropsWithoutRef<LinkProps<S>> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
) => (
  <TopReactRouterContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => (
      <RouterContext.Provider value={value}>
        <ReactRouterLink {...props} />
      </RouterContext.Provider>
    )}
  </TopReactRouterContext.Consumer>
  );
```

This Link component ignores any routers in the middle and talks only with the top one.